# HP probook 4310s quick launch keyboard sensor Wi-Fi button gone crazy- blinking

Tags: wireless, hp

I have a problem with quick launch keyboard buttons on hp probook 4310s and ubuntu 10.10. Actually, with one button- Wi-Fi on/off

In windows everything works fine, but in Ubuntu every time I turn to network and make some actions (e.g., it's happening while I'm writing this message) this button goes crazy. It starts blinking. If I just read the page-it doesn’t blink. There are no pop-up messages like “Wi-Fi connected/Wi-Fi disconnected/Wi-Fi conn…”. But network connection blinks in the company of the button.

If I try xev, the event tester doesn’t show anything-it seems I don't push it. If I try to make a new action in keyboard shortcut settings- it doesn't see I push this button in a hope to change it's assignment. Despite of this the button works. Sometimes, when it's not blinking I can push it and it changes it's colour- so, somehow it works. How can I configure this button or the whole panel? Or what driver I must install manually?

Answer (score 2):

many thanks to Tux http://idyllictux.wordpress.com
he wrote:

> `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/wlan.conf`
> Then put in the following content:
>
> `options iwlcore led_mode=1`
>
> Restart and it should work. Taken from
> gentoo wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Tip from another forum, which worked perfect for me after the quick launch buttons gave up their function from one day to another:

> remove the power cable, shutdown your laptop, remove the battery, then hold the power 
>   button of your laptop for 15 seconds and then insert the battery and restart again.

After that weird procedure my quick launch buttons worked again. It seems like magic :)